# setContentView doesn't get called when trying to call from other layout

Tags: java, android, android-studio

So I'm trying to switch layout to get a really simple 2 page app.
However when I click my back button the setContentView doesn't work.
Anyone know why and how to solve this?

Here is my code:

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button infoBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.infoBtn);
        infoBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_info);
            }
        });

        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        final View rootView = vi.inflate(R.layout.activity_info, null, true);

        Button backBtn = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.backBtn);
        backBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                System.out.println("Fired!");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Try using an Intent: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html

Comment: You need to investigate Fragments. It will help you to achieve exactly what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

calling `SetContentView()` does not create your app, so all the code you put in your `onCreate()` wont be called the second time.

That is why people use `Activity`s or `Fragment`s

you can encapsulate your oncreate codes and call them when you recall `setContentView()`

Comment: Thanks. Fragments are somehow a little bit more complicated but I have watched a few videos and its going good so far so thanks :)